# Is it reasonable to use Int64 instead of DateTime / TimeSpan in the Domain-level structures?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, domain-driven-design

I have the following simple structure in my solution's domain project (.NET Framework):

```
public struct Candlestick
{
    public DateTime OpenTime;
    public DateTime CloseTime;
    public double Open;
    public double High;
    public double Low;
    public double Close;
    public double Volume;
}
```

In my business logic I have many methods that perform time-based search in big lists of Candlestick structures. For example:

```
public static int IndexOfFirst(this IReadOnlyList<Candlestick> data, DateTime from)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

    int count = data.Count;
    if (count == 0) return -1;

    int fromIdx = 0;
    while (data[fromIdx].OpenTime < from)
    {
        if (++fromIdx == count)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return fromIdx;
}
```

Would it be generally a good idea to use the long (`Int64`) type for time variables in the Candlestick struct, so that the logic layer can operate faster with this structure? Also, I mean to keep the corresponding class on the application level (CandlestickVM in the view-model layer) with the time variables of the type `DateTime`.

To check my idea of using `Int64`, I ran a simple performance test on dotnetfiddle.net:

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2023, 01, 01);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2023, 02, 01);

TimeSpan incr = new TimeSpan(1);
DateTime now = a;
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (now < b)
{
    now += incr;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"It took {sw.Elapsed} to run the Date & Time test.");

long incr2 = incr.Ticks;
long now2 = a.Ticks;
long bticks = b.Ticks;
sw.Restart();
while (now2 < bticks)
{
    now2 += incr2;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"It took {sw.Elapsed} to run the long test.");
```

The results is as the following:

```
It took 00:00:04.8027716 to run the Date & Time test.
It took 00:00:00.9261338 to run the long test.
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is *actually* a bottleneck in your app? Rather than this very ad-hoc testing, have you tried more thorough micro-benchmarking with Benchmark.NET? (I would be pretty surprised if this turned out to actually be a bottleneck.)

Comment: Not an answer, but it might be a good idea to use something like https://benchmarkdotnet.org/ to do your testing for what is faster. Stopwatch can be a bit  unreliable for something like this.

Comment: It's worth noting that you're including the time taken for `now += incr` in your benchmark, whereas that's *not* an operation you perform in your application code as far as I can see. I don't know how expensive the DateTime+TimeSpan operator is, but it's entirely possible that it's more expensive than the comparison...

Comment: @JonSkeet You are correct pointing that out. That's my mistake of making a test different from the logic method. Also, I don't have any evidence that operations on DateTime make an actual bottleneck in my application. That was just a thought in my mind about whether it's worth optimizing the structure.

Comment: FYI, your `while` loop  in your `IndexOfFirst` method could be more concisely written as a `for` loop. The method body after the `null` check could just be: `for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) { if (data[i].OpenTime >= from) return i; } return -1;`

Comment: Unrelated side note: given this is a financial app, you may want to use `Decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: Indeed, I'd *definitely* focus on readability for now, rather than performance, until you *know* you have a performance problem. (I'd also start following the convention of *always* using braces for `if` statements, even for single-statement bodies...)

Comment: For benchmarking, you should probably run on a local machine, prioritize your thread, include a "warmup" run, try to ensure there are no garbage collections going on, compile in Release mode, and run *outside* of Visual Studio. As it is currently written, there are many external things that can affect your benchmark. Also ensure you're running both tests for the same number of iterations. The way the while looops are written, it's really hard to tell.

Comment: Also, it seems that in your application code you're only doing date comparisons, yet in your benchmark code you're doing additions with the `+=` operator. The performance difference between a `long` and a `DateTime` using `<` and `>` will likely be quite different from `+=`, as internally `DateTime` is just doing a `long` comparison of the `Ticks` property of the two items - no other bounds checking or casting involved.  See: [DateTime source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1485)

Comment: You say you have a **big** list of `Candlestick` but I would think it would not be bigger than `int.MaxValue`, i.e. around 2.1 billion.  Your test above is for 31 days, which is 2_678_400 seconds.  Since there are 10 million ticks per seconds, your loop iterates **26_784_000_000_000** times.

Comment: @RickDavin indeed. Something is spooky with the benchmark. There is no PC in the world that can do 26 trillion `long` increments in under a second, on a single thread.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the comments. You add so much clarity for understanding the subject, as well as how to correctly run benchmarks in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only operations with `DateTime` are comparisons, while your benchmark does adition. I made a simple benchmark using BenchmarkDtonet with comparisons only and here are the code and results:

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net70)]    
[RPlotExporter]
public class LongXDateTime
{
    [Params(1_000_000)]
    private int N;
    private DateTime[] Da;
    private DateTime[] Db;
    private long[] La;
    private long[] Lb;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Da = new DateTime[N];
        Db = new DateTime[N];
        La = new long[N];
        Lb = new long[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            La[i] = Random.Shared.NextInt64(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks, DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks);
            Lb[i] = Random.Shared.NextInt64(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks, DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks);
            Da[i] = new DateTime(La[i]);
            Db[i] = new DateTime(Lb[i]);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool[] LongMethod()
    {
        bool[] result = new bool[La.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < La.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = La[i] < Lb[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public bool[] DateTimeMethod()
    {
        bool[] result = new bool[Da.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Da.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Da[i] < Db[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
|         Method |          N |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|--------------- |----------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
|     LongMethod |    1000000 | 1.460 ms | 0.0253 ms | 0.0370 ms |
| DateTimeMethod |    1000000 | 1.467 ms | 0.0292 ms | 0.0380 ms |
```

So switching to long:

1. might not be relevant in terms of application performance
2. Is less readable
3. Is less safe, since you lose type safety

Also, recommend reading [Eric Lippert Blog about performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: It feels like an exhaustive and universal answer. Thank you so much for making this effort to resolving my issue!